# FILE *f initializes to what in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to have the option to either write the results to a file or not, so I would have a file name fnm, and if it's blank (`""`) I won't create/write to the file. So basically I have:

```
FILE* f;

if(fnm!=""){
//open file for writing
    f = fopen(fnm.c_str(), "a+");
}

/*do some other stuff*/

for(int idx=0;idx<n;idx++){
    printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", k, idx, A[idx]);
    if(f!=NULL){
        fprintf(f,"%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", k, idx, A[idx]);
    }
}

if(f!=NULL){
    //close the file
    fclose(f);
}
```

Now, `f` doesn't actually get initialized to `NULL` upon declaring `FILE* f;`. It works fine if I initialize it manually `FILE* f=NULL;`, so this is mostly me being curious as to the default initialization. I googled it before but the answers were for C and they said that it *is* initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: Might as well write it as `FILE* f = fopen(fnm.c_str(), "a+");` - if the filename is an empty string, `fopen` will fail and return NULL

Comment: You should probably consult the docs for VS2010 to find the best way to access a file, unless you have a GOOD REASON to do this C-style.  Further, you've also answered your own question, since C++ is an extension of C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends.

If you define `f` outside any function, *then* it will be initialized as a null pointer.

If you define `f` inside a function, then it will be initialized to garbage.

The same is true in both C and C++.

Comment: Recommend explicit initialization for any case please.

Answer (score 4):

The values of uninitialized non-static local variables is indeterminate, and using them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So don't use uninitialized local variables. Always initialize them, either directly in the definition or in a separate assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The value is undefined; you must explicitly initialize it to `NULL` in your initialization code. Likely any value found in the pointer will be the result of whatever arbitrary value the memory used to store that pointer last had.